# How to use webclient to call a webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webclient

We have a web service developed by another group that translate the amount of money in numbers into words. For example 123.45, the web service will return one hundred twenty three and forty five cents. I need to call this web service from an aspx page. I know I could use web reference. But  for some reason, web reference is not the best solution for us. I did some research, seems like WebClient can also do it. Does anybody have some example about how to call a web service through WebClient?

Answer (score 1):

Google search turned up this for you.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d09b7de-a19c-46f7-a305-efd6723557fc/calling-a-webservice-webmethod-using-webclient-class-uploadstringasync

**Code Snippet**

```
Uri _uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8081/Test.asmx");
WebClient wcClient = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nvcKeys = new NameValueCollection();
wcClient.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
wcClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Test Service 1.0");
wcClient.Headers.Add(nvcKeys);
wcClient.UploadStringAsync(_uri, "POST", "Hello World");
```

Comment: (Eventhough it is possible in theory) I haven't seen any webservice that accepts a bare string(Hello World) in body. It is generally in the form of SOAP (in asmx services),XML,Json or UrlEncoded

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that will query the web service's WSDL, generate a proxy and allow you to call the web service's methods via that proxy; essentially do what `Generate Web Reference` does in Visual Studio, but through code instead.

Read [Call a Web Service Without Adding a Web Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42278/Call-a-Web-Service-Without-Adding-a-Web-Reference).